# mongodb : how to get documents that contains nested field data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

suppose my data is

```
db.posts.save({postid:1,postdata:"hi am ",comments:["nice","whats bro"]});
```

so in this case how to iterate comments
means

```
cursor=selct * from posts;
cursor 1=selct * from comments where postid=:cursor.postid
for (i in cursor)
for(j in cursor1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to iterate over the comments would be as follows:

```
db.posts.find().forEach(
  function(doc) {
    // iterate over the comments in your preferred javascript way
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<doc.comments.length; ++i) {
      // Do whatever you want with doc.comments[i] here
    }
  }
)
```